# What are applications of Frobenius inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Frobenius inequality states that $\operatorname{rank} AB + \operatorname{rank} BC \leq \operatorname{rank} ABC + \operatorname{rank} B$ whenever this has a meaning.
I remember being told that this was sometimes useful. Do you know of any example?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081087908817301#preview

Comment: Thanks but I can't read it. :(

Answer (score 1):

The prove of Frobenius inequality plays very important role in linear algebra's problem.
you also see PROBLEMS AND THEOREMS IN LINEAR ALGEBRA by V. Prasolov (www.amazon.com/Problems-Theorems-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821802364)