# Lower bound involving the rank of the composition of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following question is about a lower bound on the rank of a composition of functions given as a simple expression for the two terms of the sum involved in the inequality.

Consider finite-dimensional vector spaces $V_1,V_2, V_3,V_4$ and linear transformations of these spaces $f_1 : V_1 \rightarrow V_2$, $f_2: V_2 \rightarrow V_3$, $f_3: V_3 \rightarrow V_4$.

Is it true that $\def\rank{\operatorname{rank}}\rank(f_3 \circ f_2) + \rank(f_2 \circ f_1) \geq  \rank(f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1) + \rank(f_2) $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Frobenius Inequality for matrices says $$R(AB)+R(BC)\le R(ABC)+R(B)$$ where $R$ is the rank (and we assume all products are defined), so maybe you have it backwards?

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72810/what-are-applications-of-frobenius-inequality) recent m.se question on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$No, this is not true in general. The left-hand side may be $0$ while the right-hand side is not. For instance, take $V_i=\mathbb R^2$ and $f_i$ all equal and given by the matrix $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ in some basis. Then the composition of any two of the transformations is the zero map, with rank $0$, but $\rank f_2=1$.