# How do I prove that $\operatorname{rank}{AB}+\operatorname{rank}{BC}\le\operatorname{rank}{B}+\operatorname{rank}{ABC}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you prove $\def\rank{\operatorname{rank}}\rank(f_3 \circ f_2) + \rank(f_2 \circ f_1) \leq \rank(f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1) + \rank(f_2) $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76002/how-do-you-prove-def-rank-operatornamerank-rankf-3-circ-f-2-rankf-2)

The Frobenius inequality of linear algebra, with $A,B,C\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$, is: $$\operatorname{rank}{AB}+\operatorname{rank}{BC}\le\operatorname{rank}{B}+\operatorname{rank}{ABC}$$

Comment: In wikipedia, I've already read the proof you referred to. What I don't understand is, what is $\ker{ABC}/\ker{BC}$ and why that projection is one-to-one?

Comment: This is also a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497830/frobenius-inequality-rank .

Answer (score 2):

To answer your more focused question in the comment:

The clear candidate map is $x\mapsto Cx +\ker (B)$, which gives you a homomorphism from $\ker(ABC)\rightarrow \ker(AB)/\ker(B)$.

Modding out by this map's kernel, which happens to be $\ker(BC)$, the new map from $\ker(ABC)/\ker(BC)\rightarrow \ker(AB)/\ker(B)$ is necessarily an injection. (This is just an isomorphism theorem.)

I'll also add that there is no indication that it is (or even needs to be) onto, so it's not really a projection.

From that point on, presumably you are working with all finite dimensional spaces, so this isomorphism gives you the inequality $\dim(\ker(ABC))-\dim(\ker(BC))\leq \dim(\ker(AB))-\dim(\ker(B))$