# Frobenius Inequality Rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was looking for an answer for this problem in terms of matrices, but I really don't know how to prove this result. The proposition says that:

Let $A\in M_{m\times k}(\mathbb{C})$, $B\in M_{k\times p}(\mathbb{C})$ and $C\in M_{p\times n}(\mathbb{C})$, then $\textrm{rank}(AB)+\textrm{rank}(BC)\leq \textrm{rank}(B)+\textrm{rank}(ABC)$

Comment: You can find a sketch proof in reference #2 in the following link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#cite_note-2. Helps?

Comment: okay, thank you, but I know this demonstration, I need one in terms of matrices

Answer (score 18):

Notation:

- $\rho(\cdot)$ stands for rank,
- $\ker(\cdot)$ for null space (aka kernel),
- $\text{im}(\cdot)$ for column space (aka image).

All we need is the following well known identity (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154998/dim-cab-dim-cb-dim-operatornamenulla-cap-cb) for a proof): 
$$\rho(AB)=\rho(B)−\dim(\text{im}(B) \cap \ker(A))
\tag{1}$$
and the following observation: $$\text{im}(BC) \cap \ker(A) \subseteq \text{im}(B)\cap \ker(A)\tag{2}$$ which holds since $\text{im}(BC)\subseteq \text{im}(B)$.

Now we want to write $\rho(ABC)$ in such a way that $\text{im}(BC)\cap \ker(A)$ pops up, so we could make use of $(2)$. Analogously to $(1)$:

$$\rho(ABC)=\rho(BC)−\dim(\text{im}(BC) \cap \ker(A))
\tag{3}.$$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$:

$$\rho(AB)+ \rho(BC) = \rho(B) + \rho(ABC)  + \underbrace{\dim(\text{im}(BC) \cap \ker(A))−\dim(\text{im}(B) \cap \ker(A))}_{\leq 0 \text{ due to } (2)}$$ which implies the desired inequality.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the Sylvester inequality then it's a two lines proof.

### Sylvester Inequality:

> Consider $A_{m\times r}$ and $B_{r\times n}$. Then 
>   $$r(AB)\geq r(A)+r(B)-r \tag{1}$$
>   where $r(\cdot)$ is the rank.

Let  $B=U_{k\times r} V_{r\times p}$ be a full-rank factorization of $B$.

Then by $(1)$,

\begin{align}
r(ABC)&\geq r(AU)+r(VC)-r\\
     &=r(AB)+r(BC)-r(B).
\end{align}

---

### For a proof of Sylvester inequality refer the following:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link or name the book from where the screenshot of Sylvester Theorem has been taken.