# If $ABC = 0$ and rank$(B) = 1$, then either $AB = 0$ or $BC = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem**

Let $A, B, C \in M_n(\mathbb{R}).$ If $ABC = 0$ and rank$(B) = 1$, then either $AB = 0$ or $BC = 0$.

**My idea**

I only know that rank$(AB) \leq$ rank$(B)=1$ and rank$(BC) \leq$ rank$(B)=1$. However, it doesn't help. Is there any inequality between rank$(B)$, rank$(AB)$, rank$(BC)$ and rank$(ABC)?$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497830/frobenius-inequality-rank)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach I like: since $B$ has rank $1$, we can write
$$
B = uv^T
$$
for some non-zero vectors $u,v \in \Bbb R$.  As such, we can rewrite
$$
ABC = Auv^TC = (Au)(C^Tv)^T
$$
It now suffices to note that for vectors $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$, we have $xy^T = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$ or $y = 0$.

Comment: can't $x,y$ be orthogonal and non zero?

Comment: @clark That isn't the inner product, though, that would be $x^Ty$, not $xy^T$.

Comment: ooops sorry for the disturbance

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $ABC=0$ and $\text{rank}\left(B\right)=1$. By Frobenius Inequality, we have
$$\text{rank}\left(AB\right)+\text{rank}\left(BC\right) \leq \text{rank} \left(B\right)+\text{rank}\left(ABC\right)=1+0=1.$$ If $\text{rank}\left(AB\right) \geq 1$ and $\text{rank}\left(BC\right) \geq 1,$ then $2\le \text{rank}\left(AB\right)+\text{rank}\left(BC\right)\le1,$ (↯). Thus, either $\text{rank}\left(AB\right)<1$ or $\text{rank}\left(BC\right)<1.$ Since $\text{rank}\left(AB\right)\ge0$ and $\text{rank}\left(BC\right)\ge0,$ then either $\text{rank}\left(AB\right)=0$ or $\text{rank}\left(BC\right)=0.$