# Nilpotent matrix and direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Let $A$ be a nilpotent matrix and suppose $A^6 = 0$ but $A^5 \neq 0$. Further, suppose the vector spaces $\mathcal V_1, \ldots, \mathcal V_6$ satisfy
$$\ker(A^{i}) = \mathcal V_1 \oplus \mathcal V_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathcal V_i.$$
Is it possible that $\dim(\mathcal V_3) = 0$?

I think that maybe we have to show $\mathcal V_3$ contains only zero vector or $\ker(A^2) = \ker(A^3)$ or something else, but don't know how to prove it. Can anyone give some hints?

Comment: It is not possible.  See my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2694593

Comment: But how can this be related to A^6 ? That's the point that I've been struggling with .

Comment: If $V_3 = 0$, then $\ker(A^3) = \ker(A^2)$.  This imples $\ker(A^k) = \ker(A^2)$ for all $k \ge 2$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that the answer I linked to concerned the decreasing sequence of ranges rather than the increasing sequence of kernels.  In the finite dimensional setting you can go back and forth via the rank-nullity theorem. In general you can find a similar proof to show that if the increasing sequence of kernels ever fails to strictly increase, then it is stable forever after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space, not necessarily finite dimensional, and $T : V \to V$ a linear operator.   Then $\ker(T^{k}) \subseteq \ker(T^{k+1})$ for all $k \ge 0$.  Suppose that for some $k$, one has equality, $\ker(T^{k}) = \ker(T^{k+1})$.    I claim that $\ker(T^l) = \ker(T^k) $ for all $l \ge k+1$. One proves this by induction as follows.  The base case $l = k+1$ holds by hypothesis.  Suppose for a particular $l \ge k+1$ one has $\ker(T^l) = \ker(T^k) $.  Let $v \in \ker(T^{l + 1})$.  Then $T v \in \ker(T^l) = \ker(T^k)$, and thus $0 = T^k(T v) = T^{k+1} v$, so $v \in \ker(T^{k+1}) = \ker(T^k)$.  This shows $\ker(T^{l+1}) \subseteq \ker(T^k)$. The opposite containment is obvious, so $\ker(T^{l+1}) = \ker(T^k)$.  This completes the induction.

In the specific problem, if $V_3 = 0$, then $\ker(A^3) = \ker(A^2)$.  Hence $\ker(A^l) = \ker(A^2)$ for all $l \ge 3$. In particular, $\ker(A^6) = \ker(A^5) = \ker(A^2)$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: Although I've solved it by myself, thanks for your hints !