# Inequality involving ranks

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove the following inequality,

$$
\rho(AB) + \rho(BC) \le \rho(B) + \rho(ABC)
$$

where $A, B, C \in L(V)$, $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $\rho(A)$ means the rank of the linear operator $A$.

I know that $\min(\rho(AB), \rho(BC)) \le \rho(B)$. So I tried to prove that $\max(\rho(AB), \rho(BC)) \le \rho(ABC))$ but couldn't get anywhere.

Any hint is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Frobenius Inequality Rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497830/frobenius-inequality-rank)

Comment: It does, indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It is helpful to rewrite the inequality as follows:
$$
\rho(B) - \rho(AB) \geq \rho(BC) - \rho(ABC)
$$
Similarly, we could write $\rho(B) - \rho(BC) \geq \rho(AB) - \rho(ABC)$.

---

**Further hint:** Note that $\rho(AB) = \rho(B) - \dim(\ker(A) \cap \operatorname{im}(B))$, where "im" denotes the image/range and "ker" denotes the kernel/nullspace.

We can prove this as follows: let $T$ denote the map $T:\operatorname{im}(B) \to V$ defined by $T(x) = A(x)$ (i.e. $T = A|_{\operatorname{im}(B)}$, the restriction of $A$ to $\operatorname{im}(B)$). We note that $\rho(T) = \rho(AB)$, and by the rank-nullity theorem we have
$$
\rho(T) = \dim\operatorname{im}(B) - \dim \ker (T) = \rho(B) - \dim (\ker(A) \cap \operatorname{im} (B)).
$$
Similarly, we observe that $\rho(A[BC]) = \rho(BC) - \dim(\ker(A) \cap \operatorname{im}(BC))$.

Comment: Using your hint and the fact that $\rho(A + B) \le \rho(A) + \rho(B)$ I found $\rho(BC) - \rho(ABC) \le \rho((B-AB)C) \le \rho(B - AB)$ but got stuck again. I'll be very grateful for any further help.

Comment: @Izralbu See my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Using Interpretation.

$A|_{U}$will refer to operator $A:V\mapsto W$ acting on an subspace $U\subseteq V$.

$\text{dim}\text{Ker}A|_{U} \leq \text{dim}\text{Ker}A=\text{dim}V-\text{dim}\text{Im}A$

Now we're gonna use the above but with $V=\operatorname{Im}A,U=\operatorname{Im}BC$
.Now using the Product inequlaity on $AB$ and $A$ along with the :

$$\text{dim}\text{Ker}A|_{\text{Im}BC}=\text{dim}\text{Im}BC-\text{dim}\text{Im}ABC$$
.

Comment: What does "using interpretation" mean?