# If $Rank(A^2) = Rank(A)$, then $Rank(A^3) = Rank(A)$, where $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

I want to determine if the above statement is true or false, and if it is false, give a counter-example. I know for a fact that it it true. But, I am not sure if this proof is entirely correct or not: 
$Image(A^2) \subseteq Image(A)$, but $dim(Image(A^2))=dim(Image(A))$, so we must have that $Image(A^2)=Image(A)$, and thus, $A^2=A$. So, $A^3=A^2=A$, and hence, $Rank(A^3)=Rank(A)$.

I am not entirely sure if the reasoning $Image(A^2)=Image(A) \implies A^2=A$ is correct or not. 

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can help me with that!

Comment: Look at $A=-I$ to see why you are wrong.

Comment: It should have been apparent to you when you wrongly concluded $A^2=A$ must be true in this case.

Comment: Why don't you apply $A$ to both sides of the equality ${\rm Im}A={\rm Im} A^2$ ?

Comment: @geetha290krm you are right, my reasoning is incorrect, but can you please give me a hint as to how to proceed with this question?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc What do you mean "apply" $A$ to both sides of the equality. I am sorry, I am fairly new to linear algebra.

Comment: If ${\rm Im}A={\rm Im }(A^2)$ then ${\rm Im}(A^2)=A({\rm Im}A)=A({\rm Im }(A^2))={\rm Im}(A^3).$ Hence  ${\rm Im}A={\rm Im}(A^3).$ Thus ${\rm rank}(A)={\rm rank}(A^3).$

Comment: Thank you so much @RyszardSzwarc!, I got it!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc your comment looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Frobenius Rank Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/497830/934187) as

$rank(A^3) \ge rank(A^2) + rank(A^2) - rank(A)$

$\implies rank(A^3) \ge rank(A)$

And also $rank(A^3) \le min\{rank(A^2),rank(A)\}$

$\implies rank(A^3) \le rank(A)$

And we get $rank(A^3)=rank(A)$.